# Database error InValidOperationException when attempting to save to database

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I get this error when I attempt to save to the database.
In the Controller I have the Edit HttpPut

```
 public ActionResult EditSubject(Models.xxxx model)
 {
    //Database Model Class    
    SubjectDB subjectdb = new SubjectDB();
    // Name of DB Access in Web.config
    BeaconDBEntities db = new BeaconDBEntities();


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        subjectdb.SubjectId = model.SubjectId;

        db.SubjectDBs.Add(subjectdb);   --> Pops InvalidOperationsException
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

In Models folder is the model for the database table

SubjectDB.cs

```
    namespace xxx.Models
    {
       public class SubjectDB
       {
          public string SubjectId { get; set;}
       }
       public class BeaconDBEntities: DbContext
       {
           public DbSet<SubjectDB> SubjectDBs { get; set; }
       }
    }
```

Web.config is the connect string for the database

```
    <coneectionStrings>
       <add name="BeaconDBEntities" ...............
    </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that your connection string name 'BeaconDBEntites' does not match your DbContext inherited class name 'BeaconDBEntities' (you are missing an 'i' in the word Entities). Try changing that and see if it fixes it.

Comment: That was a typo on my part. The only thing I found so far is I had a space between BeaconDBEntities^: DbContext. It should have been BeaconDBEntites: DbContext. But it still pops the same error.

Comment: what is the message of the exception say? It seems like it is hitting SQL successfully, because you would get a different exception. Are you fulfilling all the constraints for the table in the DB?

Comment: The only other thing I see is a addtional comment that says "The entity type SubjectDB is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the connection string is correct. Can we see the whole connection string (obviously X out the server info and credentials!). Did you put this into the correct web.config? There are two in MVC projects, one in the View folder and one in the main project directory. The connection string needs to be in the web.config in the main directory. Also, where did you get the connection string from? It often causes problems if you copy it directly from a'.edmx' file. Also, are you referencing the same version of EF version if you have the model classes in a different project?

Comment: Also, did you ever fix the type of the missing 'i' in your web.config for 'BeaconDBEntites' (from my original answer)?

Comment: The connect string is in the main directory. It reads <add nme="BeaconDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BeaconDB.cds1|res://*/BeaconDB.ssdl:res://*/BeaconDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxx\BEACONExpress;initial catalog=BeaconDB;integrated security=true;multipleactiveresultsets=true;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: Ok, the issue is with the connection string I think. It has a bunch of stuff specific to edmx files, that are not needed in the actual web config for the site. try something like this: <add name="BeaconDBEntities" connectionString="Data Source=xxx\BEACONExpress;Initial Catalog=BeaconDB;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> (obviously put in your actual server name instead of xxx)

Comment: The connect string is in the main directory. It reads <add name="BeaconDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BeaconDB.cds1|res://*/BeaconDB.ssdl:res://*/B‌​eaconDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxx\BEACONExpress;initial catalog=BeaconDB;integrated security=true;multipleactiveresultsets=true;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: That was the same message you had last time? Did you change anything?

Comment: Now I get an ArgumentException.

Comment: It says Key Word Data Source not supported

Comment: Why do you still have all the extra stuff i told you to try and remove? Try making the connection string this: <add name="BeaconDBEntities" connectionString="Data Source=xxx\BEACONExpress;Initial Catalog=BeaconDB;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> and just replace the server name, that is all!

Comment: What I have is <add name="BeaconDBEntities" connectionString="Data Source=6xx_xxx\BEACONExpress;Intial Catalog=BeaconDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />......I still get the ArgumentException-Keyword not supported 'Data Source'

Comment: another thing i noticed is your first connection string tag  <coneectionStrings> is also spelled wrong, can you correct that as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit your data then i think you don't need to write code like this when your useing entity framework it's below code

```
db.SubjecDBs.Add(subjectdb);   
        db.SaveChanges();
```

first when you update your data then first your get your data with your id like this it's below
and your create object your entity class. your entity class is your table like below

```
SubjecDBs objsub=new SubjecDBs();

var data =db.db.SubjecDBs.where(x=>x.SubjectID==ID).ToList();
```

then you match your data which is you wont to update like below

```
objsub.SubjecName=data[0].SubjecName
```

and you match your field which you wont to update then your write below code like this

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

i think this will help you...

Comment: I tried your way and get the same error here --- var data =db.SubjectDBs.where(x=>x.SubjectId==model.Id).ToList();

Comment: you don't write model.id  public ActionResult EditSubject(int Id)
 {} this is your action you write var data =db.SubjectDBs.where(x=>x.SubjectId==Id).ToList();